# How do I display string values on a plot instead of intergers using some seaborn histogram plot?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, type-conversion, seaborn

I am trying to create a histrogram of male and female participants from a dataframe. Currently, integer values represent each sex but I want the plot to display the string value that the integer represents on the axis. My current code looks like this.

```
# Investigating the gender of participants

# 1 = male, 2 = female

data.Gender = data.Gender.astype(str)
data.Gender[data.Gender == '1'] = 'male'
data.Gender[data.Gender == '2'] = 'female'

genderPlot = sns.histplot(data.Gender, bins=2, discrete=True);
```

Is there an easier way of doing this without having to convert the data? Also, is there a cleaner way of converting the data from an integer to a string or even male and female categories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited:

I assume this is the result you want, without replacing the data itself, just changing the labels on the plot:

```
genderPlot = sns.histplot(data['Gender'], bins=2, discrete=True);
genderPlot.set_xticks(data['Gender'].unique())
genderPlot.set_xticklabels(['male', 'female']);
```

[image]

Comment: I get the following error

AttributeError: 'PolyCollection' object has no property 'xticklabels'

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I wanted. I just found set_xticklabels and was about to test it out.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer narrowly solves the problem, but I'd mention that changing the labels in this way is a little risky because your code assumes that the bars are in a particular order and this might not always be true. With numbers encoded as strings, the bars will appear in the order that unique values appear in the dataset, so if your data slightly change, you could end up with an incorrect plot.

It's safer to try and do this mapping programatically. If you don't want to modify your original dataset, you can transform the values as you pass them to seaborn:

```
gender_map = {"1": "male", "2": "female"}
sns.histplot(data['Gender'].map(gender_map))
```

(As a side-note, you don't need to specify the number of bins with `discrete=True`, and passing string data will imply `discrete=True` so you can leave that out here too).

Comment: Thanks. This is a good point and something I've already had to deal with, very useful!